# React onClick not firing for unkown reason

Tags: reactjs

This react onClick doesn't seem to be firing. Seems perfectly normal, I've got no idea why.

```
 console.log('rendered');
  const [taskWindowState, setTaskWindowState] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const setTaskState = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
    setTaskWindowState(true);
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.Page}>
      {taskWindowState ? <AddTask /> : null}
      <div className={styles.PlusCircleHolder} onClick={setTaskState}>
        <object type='image/svg+xml' data='/plus-circle.svg' className={styles.add}/>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.todo}>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

it doesn't come up with 'clicked' in the console. I've checked that the div is covering the SVG completely, so I've been clicking on the div. It just doesn't seem to be firing for an unknown reason.

Comment: Can u try using `this.setTaskState`?

Comment: @TechySharnav It's a functional component, not a class component.

Comment: Is it possible to create a codesandbox for this? Seems hard to resolve it like this

Comment: Actually, I Tried in sandbox, and the 'clicked' is getting logged in console. (after modifying a bit of code).  

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-chatelet-9d5o1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @TechySharnav Do you think it's a problem with react then. How would I go by fixing this?

Comment: @Oliver Huth I would like to know, why are you passing styles to class name? Also, what's `<boolean>` in 2nd line of code?

Comment: @TechySharnav It's [TypeScript syntax](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/hooks#usestate).

Comment: Oh, okay.  I think its the overlapping issue only.  The code seems correct.

Comment: @TechySharnav and the `styles` object being passed to `className` is presumably because [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) are being used

Comment: update child with pointer-event: none and check if it works!!

Comment: @Sajz OMG thank you so much!! it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding `pointer-event: none` to my css code for my svg.

Answer (score 0):

@oliver, welcome. Please mark this as answer.

Update child with pointer-event: none and it will work.